# Get variable & put inside other input

Tags: jquery

This is my script:

```
jQuery('#postcustomstuff tbody > tr:nth-child(3)').click(function () {

    // Get IDs
    var poleRatingsAverage  =   jQuery('#postcustomstuff tbody > tr:nth-child(2)').attr('id');
    var poleRatingsUsers    =   jQuery('#postcustomstuff tbody > tr:nth-child(4)').attr('id');
    var poleRatingsScore    =   jQuery('#postcustomstuff tbody > tr:nth-child(3)').attr('id');

    var ratings_average = jQuery(poleRatingsUsersTextAreaID).val();
    var ratings_users = jQuery(poleRatingsUsersTextAreaID).val();
    var ratings_score = parseInt(ratings_average) * parseInt(ratings_users);

})
```

I have one problem with my jQuery script. I must get IDs from variables: `poleRatingsAverage`, `poleRatingsUsers` and `poleRatingsScore`. I tried this:

```
alert(poleRatingsAverage); <---- This return good but in next part I must add VALUE to this:

// Values Start
var ratings_average = jQuery(poleRatingsAverage+'-value').val();
var ratings_users = jQuery(poleRatingsUsers+'-value').val();
var ratings_score = parseInt(ratings_average) * parseInt(ratings_users);

jQuery(poleRatingsScore+'-value').val(ratings_score); // Math
// Values End
```

What am I doing wrong in my script?

Comment: Is it as simple as putting `#` in front of all the query selectors?  Just put `poleRatingsAverage = "#" + poleRatingsAverage;` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this returns value of elements id

```
alert(poleRatingsAverage);
```

here you are trying to get other elements that have similar id with "-value" on the end of that id

```
// Values Start
var ratings_average = jQuery(poleRatingsAverage+'-value').val();
var ratings_users = jQuery(poleRatingsUsers+'-value').val();
var ratings_score = parseInt(ratings_average) * parseInt(ratings_users);
jQuery(poleRatingsScore+'-value').val(ratings_score); // Math
// Values End
```

So what you are missing is

```
jQuery('#'+poleRatingsAverage+'-value').val();
```

You must say to jquery that you are looking for an id with specific value

Comment: You don't know whether or not there is a hash at the front of `poleRatingsAverage`, so you shouldn't post this is an answer as it may be totally wrong.  You should get more information before you act.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! It's works!

This is script after editing :

```
jQuery('#postcustomstuff tbody > tr:nth-child(3)').click(function () {

    // Get IDs
    var poleRatingsAverage  =   jQuery('#postcustomstuff tbody > tr:nth-child(2)').attr('id');
    var poleRatingsUsers    =   jQuery('#postcustomstuff tbody > tr:nth-child(4)').attr('id');
    var poleRatingsScore    =   jQuery('#postcustomstuff tbody > tr:nth-child(3)').attr('id');

    var ratings_average = jQuery('#'+poleRatingsAverage+'-value').val();
    var ratings_users = jQuery('#'+poleRatingsUsers+'-value').val();
    var ratings_score = parseInt(ratings_average) * parseInt(ratings_users);

    jQuery('#'+poleRatingsScore+'-value').val(ratings_score);

})
```

Very, very, very THANKS for help !